# Monthly Birthday SQL Query

Tags: sql, mysql

How would retrieve all customer's birthdays for a given month in SQL? What about MySQL?
I was thinking of using the following with SQL server.

```
select c.name   
from cust c
where  datename(m,c.birthdate) = datename(m,@suppliedDate)
order by c.name
```

Comment: why wouldn't that work for mysql? surely they have a datepart() equivalent?

Comment: EXTRACT seems to do what I assume datepart() does. eg: SELECT EXTRACT (day FROM `myDate`). There are individual functions for each part though (day(), month(), year(), etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't forget the 29th February...

```
SELECT c.name
FROM cust c
WHERE (
    MONTH(c.birthdate) = MONTH(@suppliedDate)
    AND DAY(c.birthdate) = DAY(@suppliedDate)
) OR (
    MONTH(c.birthdate) = 2 AND DAY(c.birthdate) = 29
    AND MONTH(@suppliedDate) = 3 AND DAY(@suppliedDate) = 1
    AND (YEAR(@suppliedDate) % 4 = 0) AND ((YEAR(@suppliedDate) % 100 != 0) OR (YEAR(@suppliedDate) % 400 = 0))
)
```

Comment: The legal birthday for someone born on Feb 29 actually depends on the locale - [according to Wikipedia][1], it is february 28th in England, for example. 

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29#Births

Comment: well in that case, adjust accordingly.

Comment: Nice :-) Wisdom like that can only come from experience :-)

Comment: Very good solution, but Wouldn't these date functions make the query pretty slow on a large dataset?  Might be better off using >= @first day of_this_month AND <= @last_day_of_this_month

Comment: yeah, this answer doesn't actually answer the question, which was about birth MONTHS, not birth DAYS. I only realised this afterwards. The other answerers read the question a bit closer than I did...

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use DATEPART instead of DATENAME as DATENAME is open to interpretation depending on locale.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for all birthdays in a given *month*, then you should supply the *month*, not a *date*:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM   cust c
WHERE  datepart(m,c.birthdate) = @SuppliedMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually be tempted to add a birthmonth column, if you expect the list of customers to get very large. So far, the queries I've seen (including the example) will require a full table scan, as you're passing the the data column to a function and comparing that. If the table is of any size, this could take a fair amount of time since no index is going to be able to help.

So, I'd add the birthmonth column (indexed) and just do (with possible MySQLisms):

```
SELECT name
FROM  cust
WHERE birthmonth = MONTH(NOW())
ORDER BY name;
```

Of course, it should be easy to set the birthmonth column either with a trigger or with your client code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *  FROM tbl_Employee  WHERE DATEADD( Year, DATEPART( Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART( Year, DOB), DOB)  BETWEEN CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() + 30)
```

This can be use to get the upcoming Birthday by days